# Can I separately train a classifier (e.g. SVM) with two different types of features and combine the results later?

Tags: classification

I am a student and working on my first simple machine learning project. The project is about classifying articles into fake and true. I want to use SVM as classification algorithm and two different types of features:

1. TF-IDF
2. Lexical Features like the count of exclamation marks and numbers

I have figured out how to use the lexical features and TF-IDF as a features separately. However, I have not managed to figure out, how to combine them.

**Is it possible, to train and test two separate learning algorithms (one with TF-IDF and the other one with lexical features) and later combine the results?**

For example, can I calculate Accuracy, Precision and Recall for both separately and then take the average?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of combining two models is called model stacking. The idea behind it is, that you take the predictions of both models and feed them into a third model (called meta-model) which is then trained to make predictions given the output of the first two models. There is also another version of model stacking where you aditionally feed the original features into the meta-model.

However, in your case another way to combine both approaches would be to simply feed both the TF-IDF and the lexical features into one model and see how that performs.

> For example, can I calculate Accuracy, Precision and Recall for both separately and then take the average?

This would unfortunately not work, because there is no combined model making those predictions for which your calculated metrics would be true.